# Routing in angular 2

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I have a Client folder. In the Client folder, i have a modal form file for adding. In the same Client folder, i have a table.html file. Now in the table.html file, i have fa fa-plus button. How can i trigger the modal form when i press the fa fa-plus which happens to be in the table.html. Below is my code. Any assistance please?

//Modal form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add</h4>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">

          <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" >



            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="first_name"> First Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" [(ngModel)]="user.first_name" name="first_name" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name"  [(ngModel)]="user.last_name" name="last_name" required>
            </div>

   <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger ">Cancel</button>
            </div>

          </form>
          </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
```

//table.html

```
 <td><a class="btn btn-success" ><em class="fa fa-plus"></em></a></td>
```